# Annotation @Builder with problem in Java 21

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, lombok

I have a problem with Lombok's [@Builder](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) annotation. I am using Lombok version `1.18.30` with Java 21.
The actual error can be seen in the images attached to my question.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P1jZ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/423gG.png

The error message if I compile the project with my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA):

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method userMessage(java.lang.String)
  location: class com.api.mscompras.controller.exceptionHandler.Problem.ProblemBuilder
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `new Problem.Object.Builder()` or something like that?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because code should be posted as formatted text and not as images. Refer to: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Please put together a small project where the problem can be reproduced, and share it through Github.

Answer (score -1):

Please instantiate your `Object` with the builder construct this way:

```java
    Problem.Object.builder()
        .name("name")
        .build();
```

Here is a minimal PoC - please revisit your code based on the code above and let us know if it is still not working.

Here is your POJO annotated with Lombok and Jackson's `@JsonInclude` (which is not relevant in the issue, I reckon):

```java
    @Getter
    @Builder
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    public class Problem {
    
        private int status;
        private OffsetDateTime timestamp;
        private String type;
        private String title;
        private String detail;
        private String message;
    
        @Getter
        @Builder
        public static class Object {
            private String name;
            private String userMessage;
        }
    }
```

It should work using the standard [Lombok Builder](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) construct:

```java
    class ProblemTest {
    
        @Test
        void testProblemObjectShouldBeCreated() {
            final var builtObject = Problem.Object.builder()
                .name("name")
                .userMessage("userMessage")
                .build();
    
            assertNotNull(builtObject);
            assertEquals("name", builtObject.getName());
            assertEquals("userMessage", builtObject.getUserMessage());
        }
    
    }
```